# Ommiting subject after "and"

Tags: commas, coordination, subject-pronoun-drop

I looked at this answer but it didn't solved my doubt:

[Do I need to use a comma if a subject follows "and" in a sentence?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/52482/32559)

Source:
https://fee.org/articles/would-you-press-the-button/

> Careful analysis of these questions suggests that everyone – regardless of the considerations above – should want to press the button, and presents practical strategies for actually doing so.

The subject of the last indepedent clause is "careful analysis of these questions", so it is the same subject  of the first one. I don't think the comma before the "and" can be omitted. *Shouldn't there be a "it" added after the "and"?*

Comment: It's not a  clear sentence.

Answer (score 1):

From a strictly grammatical standpoint, you are correct. The comma interrupts two clauses that have the same subject. If you did add "it" after "and," the sentence would be exactly correct.

What happens in the real world, however, is that we add commas for clarity. The typical reader may understand that the first clause ends with "button," but some readers may need more help. The longer the clause, the more helpful the comma will be.